# My Java Fraction Calculator refuses to cooperate with me

Tags: java

I've been trying to get my program to function properly although for some reason it has not been working. I am almost certain everything works all up until the point it reaches the if loops to actually execute the calculations. For some odd reason when I do op.equals(plus) or whichever operation I'd like to test, it just doesn't acknowledge that they're equal. I've tried countless variations to see if they'd work but I still remain unsuccessful. I would truly appreciate if anyone could take a look at my code and perhaps make corrections or fix it.

```
public class FracCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int repeat = 1; 
        while (repeat == 1) {
            System.out.println("Input your equation");
            String equation = input.nextLine(); // Takes the user input and sets it equal to a variable (equation)
            produceAnswer(equation);
            if(equation.equals("quit")) { // If the user inputs 'quit'
                System.out.println("You've quit out of the calculator."); 
                repeat = 2; // repeat is set to 2 so the program can no longer run and it terminates.
            }
        }
    }
    public static String produceAnswer(String input) {

        Scanner fraction = new Scanner(input); 
        String num1 = fraction.next(); 
        String op = fraction.next();
        String num2 = fraction.next(); 
        // Creates an empty string for each necessary variable for values to be added to them later on.
        String plus = "+";
        String multiply = "*";
        String division = "/";
        String subtract = "-";
        String whole = ""; 
        String numer = "";
        String denom = "";
        String whole2 = "";
        String numer2 = "";
        String denom2 = "";
        // Creates variables ansnum and ansden to be manipulated later on in the calculations.
        int ansnum = 0;
        int ansden = 0;
        // Creates place and place2 to act as counters to go through each token of the original equation input.
        int place = 0;
        int place2 = 0;
        String input1 = ""; // Sets an empty string variable for the return.
        if(num1.contains("_")) { // If the first fraction contains an _
            while(num1.charAt(place) != '_') { // while the place (index) isn't equal to that _
                whole += num1.charAt(place); // Set everything before it, equal to whole.
                place++; // Each time increase the place (index) by 1.
            }
            place++; // Increases the place by 1 to pass the _ and move onto the next part of the fraction
            if(num1.contains("/")) { // If the first fraction contains a forward slash
                while(num1.charAt(place) != '/') { // While the place does not equal its index
                    numer += num1.charAt(place); // Add every thing before it to a variable called numer
                    place++; // Each time increases the place (index) by 1.
                }
             place++; // Increases the place by 1 to pass the / and move onto the denominator.
            }
            while(place != num1.length()) { // While the place (index) is less than the length of fraction 1
                denom += num1.charAt(place); // Add every thing before it equal to the denom variable.
                place++; // Each time increases the place (index) by 1.
            }
            place++;
            // Same process as above is repeated for fraction 2.
            if(num2.contains("_")) { 
                while(num2.charAt(place2) != '_') {
                    whole2 += num2.charAt(place2);
                    place2++;
                }
                place2++;
                if(num2.contains("/")) {
                    while(num2.charAt(place2) != '/') {
                        numer2 += num2.charAt(place2);
                        place2++;
                    }
                place2++;
                }
            while(place2 != num2.length()) {
                denom2 += num2.charAt(place2);
                place2++;
            }   
         }
        // All those string variables with the values are converted into integers to be used in calculations.
        int wholenum = Integer.parseInt(whole);
        int wholenum2 = Integer.parseInt(whole2);
        int numerator1 = Integer.parseInt(numer);
        int denominator1 = Integer.parseInt(denom);
        int numerator2 = Integer.parseInt(numer2);
        int denominator2 = Integer.parseInt(denom2);

        // Calculates the whole number into the fraction to get rid of any mixed numbers.
        int wholenumerator1 = ((wholenum * denominator1) + numerator1);
        int wholenumerator2 = ((wholenum2 * denominator2) + numerator2);

        if(op.equals(plus)) { // If the operator is addition
            ansnum = ((wholenumerator1 * denominator2) + (denominator1 * wholenumerator2)); // Cross multiply to get the numerator.
            ansden = (denominator1 * denominator2); // Multiply both denominators to get a common denominator.
            input1 = (ansnum + "/" + ansden);
            System.out.println(input1);
            }
        else if(op.equals("multiply")) { // If the operator is multiplication
            ansnum = (wholenumerator1 * wholenumerator2); // multiples both numerators.
            ansden = (denominator1 * denominator2); // multiplies both denominators
            input1 = (ansnum + "/" + ansden);
            System.out.println(input1);
            }
        else if(op.equals("division")) { // If the operator is division
            ansnum = (wholenumerator1 * denominator2); // multiplies numerator1 by the reciprocal of fraction 2 (denominator2)
            ansden = (denominator1 * wholenumerator2); // multiplies denominator 1 by numerator2.
            input1 = (ansnum + "/" + ansden);
            System.out.println(input1);
            }
        else if(op.equals("subtract")) {    
            ansnum = ((wholenumerator1 * denominator2) - (wholenumerator2 * denominator1)); // multiplies numerator1 by denominator 2 and numerator 2 by denominator 1
            ansden = (denominator1 * denominator2); // multiples both denominators to find a common denominator
            input1 = (ansnum + "/" + ansden);
            System.out.println(input1);
        }
    }
        return input1;
}
```

}

Comment: did you try debugging the code

Comment: Yes, I did. Technically, there is nothing wrong with it though. It just doesn't run through the if loops so it skips over them and just returns input1 and because the value of input1 is only updated within the if loops, it remains as " ".

Comment: Why are you using '' in your while, you should use "".

Comment: I made a mistake while transferring the code over, where it says op.equals("multiply") I did not mean to put quotation marks, the same goes for division and subtract. But in the while loops, the single quotation marks seem to work fine. It gives me the values of the equation without an issue.

Comment: *"Yes you debugged. Nothing wrong. Except doesn't run through the if loops".* So there *is* something wrong (other than the term "if loop" which is meaningless, since an `if` statement is not a loop). You step through the code, and check the value of `op` when on the `if` **statement**.

Comment: My apologies for using incorrect terminology, I am still a beginner to Java. I'm not sure that I follow what you are saying though, once it reaches the if statement, it should acknowledge that op is equal to one of the operations but instead it does not for any of them.

Comment: One error is that your code formatting sucks. Fix the indentations, and it'll become very clear to you why your code is flawed. Down at the bottom, there are **4** end-braces (`}`). The last is the end-of-class. The 2nd-last is the end-of-method. The 4th-last is the end-of-else-if. Where do **you** think the 3rd-last one starts?

Comment: Honestly, I am unsure of where the 3rd-last-one starts, I recall the program saying I was missing an end brace so I had added one. All I know is that if I get rid of it, the program will not run.

Comment: Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You didn't say what the input is, so how can we verify? Took me a while to figure your parsing out, then I tried with `"1_2/3 + 4_5/6"` (`1⅔ + 4⅚`), and it printed `117/18`. That worked. Hmmm.....

Comment: So you just type random keys until it compiles? Is that how you intend to program? *Yikes!* Format your code!!!! You'll find where it starts. Because you definitely shouldn't have added it where you did.

Comment: Yeah, that's a mistake I've definitely learned from after writing this program. I am only a junior in high school that has been coding for about two months now so I am still learning. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FracCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int repeat = 1;
        while (repeat == 1) {
            System.out.println("Input your equation");
            String equation = input.nextLine(); // Takes the user input and sets it equal to a variable (equation)
            if (equation.equals("quit")) { // If the user inputs 'quit'
                System.out.println("You've quit out of the calculator.");
                repeat = 2; // repeat is set to 2 so the program can no longer run and it terminates.
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + produceAnswer(equation));//EDIT
            }
        }
    }

    public static String produceAnswer(String input) {

        Scanner fraction = new Scanner(input);
        String num1 = fraction.next().trim();
        String op = fraction.next().trim();
        String num2 = fraction.next().trim();
        // Creates an empty string for each necessary variable for values to be added to them later on.
        String plus = "+";
        String multiply = "*";
        String division = "/";
        String subtract = "-";
        String whole = "";
        String numer = "";
        String denom = "";
        String whole2 = "";
        String numer2 = "";
        String denom2 = "";
        // Creates variables ansnum and ansden to be manipulated later on in the calculations.
        int ansnum = 0;
        int ansden = 0;
        // Creates place and place2 to act as counters to go through each token of the original equation input.
        int place = 0;
        int place2 = 0;
        String input1 = ""; // Sets an empty string variable for the return.
        if (num1.contains("_")) { // If the first fraction contains an _
            while (num1.charAt(place) != '_') { // while the place (index) isn't equal to that _
                whole += num1.charAt(place); // Set everything before it, equal to whole.
                place++; // Each time increase the place (index) by 1.
            }
            place++; // Increases the place by 1 to pass the _ and move onto the next part of the fraction
        }//EDIT
        if (num1.contains("/")) { // If the first fraction contains a forward slash
            while (num1.charAt(place) != '/') { // While the place does not equal its index
                numer += num1.charAt(place); // Add every thing before it to a variable called numer
                place++; // Each time increases the place (index) by 1.
            }
            place++; // Increases the place by 1 to pass the / and move onto the denominator.
        }//EDIT
        while (place != num1.length()) { // While the place (index) is less than the length of fraction 1
            denom += num1.charAt(place); // Add every thing before it equal to the denom variable.
            place++; // Each time increases the place (index) by 1.
        }
        place++;
        // Same process as above is repeated for fraction 2.
        if (num2.contains("_")) {
            while (num2.charAt(place2) != '_') {
                whole2 += num2.charAt(place2);
                place2++;
            }
            place2++;
        }//EDIT
        if (num2.contains("/")) {
            while (num2.charAt(place2) != '/') {
                numer2 += num2.charAt(place2);
                place2++;
            }
            place2++;
        }//EDIT
        while (place2 != num2.length()) {
            denom2 += num2.charAt(place2);
            place2++;
        }

        // All those string variables with the values are converted into integers to be used in calculations.
        int wholenum = (whole.equals("")) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(whole);//EDIT
        int wholenum2 = (whole2.equals("")) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(whole2);//EDIT
        int numerator1 = Integer.parseInt(numer);
        int denominator1 = Integer.parseInt(denom);
        int numerator2 = Integer.parseInt(numer2);
        int denominator2 = Integer.parseInt(denom2);

        // Calculates the whole number into the fraction to get rid of any mixed numbers.
        int wholenumerator1 = ((wholenum * denominator1) + numerator1);
        int wholenumerator2 = ((wholenum2 * denominator2) + numerator2);

        if (op.equals(plus)) { // If the operator is addition
            ansnum = ((wholenumerator1 * denominator2) + (denominator1 * wholenumerator2)); // Cross multiply to get the numerator.
            ansden = (denominator1 * denominator2); // Multiply both denominators to get a common denominator.
        } else if (op.equals(multiply)) { // If the operator is multiplication
            ansnum = (wholenumerator1 * wholenumerator2); // multiples both numerators.
            ansden = (denominator1 * denominator2); // multiplies both denominators
        } else if (op.equals(division)) { // If the operator is division
            ansnum = (wholenumerator1 * denominator2); // multiplies numerator1 by the reciprocal of fraction 2 (denominator2)
            ansden = (denominator1 * wholenumerator2); // multiplies denominator 1 by numerator2.
        } else if (op.equals(subtract)) {
            ansnum = ((wholenumerator1 * denominator2) - (wholenumerator2 * denominator1)); // multiplies numerator1 by denominator 2 and numerator 2 by denominator 1
            ansden = (denominator1 * denominator2); // multiples both denominators to find a common denominator
        }
        input1 = (ansnum + "/" + ansden);//EDIT
        return input1;
    }
}
```

*I have marked the changes as "//EDIT".*

**If this works, mark it as solution.**

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much for making the corrections. My next step is to get whole numbers to work when calculated with another whole number or fraction. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Tip: If you're using Eclipse, highlight everything and press ctrl-i to properly indent your code. You'll see your error.

Also, instead of having repeat==1 as your condition and then switching repeat=2, just use an infinite while loop with a break statement.

Comment: I corrected the indentation using control i and have also put the end brace in the correct place but the program still only works when the user inputs a mixed number. I can't seem to figure out why it does not work when the user inputs fractions.